# data in local storage does not persist after closing and reoping app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using local storage to hold just one number (best score) in my game and it works just fine when playing the game..I can play multiple rounds and it correctly shows the top score but as soon as I close totally close the app and reopen, the best score is gone.

Controller:

```
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function () {

    if(window.localStorage.getItem("topscore")<$rootScope.totalscore){

        window.localStorage.setItem("topscore", $rootScope.totalscore);
        window.localStorage.setItem("password", "yessir");
        $scope.bestscore=window.localStorage.getItem("topscore");
    }

    });
```

HTML:

```
BESTSCORE: {{bestscore}}
```

Using ionic framework and testing on actual iphone 6 device. Thanks for the help

Comment: In the subject, should "date" be "data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that function is called when your application starts up then you probably don't yet have totalScore value on your root scope. Nonetheless you seem to go ahead and set that value into local storage under the "topscore" key.

Basically, you are writing over the key whenever the application starts.

Answer (score 1):

This bit should probably be outside the `if` clause so that the value is always loaded when your thing starts up. I also added a type conversion because `localStorage` only deals in strings, and a default value in case it's not set.

```
$scope.bestscore = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("topscore") || "0", 10);
```